# Footprint of a looping ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, performance

There are a few questions of StackOverflow from people who are looking for a way to implement a looping/circular ViewPager. A ViewPager that loops to the first page when moved to last_page+1 and to the last page when moved to first_page-1.

Almost all answers suggest to give a very large number for pagecount and map those to actual pages.

Even tough all pages are created from scratch on demand, I wonder what would be the performance implications of such an approach? Will it affect the performance of my application badly? What about memory footprint?